# USB-C connector locking mechnism?

Tags: usb, usb-c

Is there an internal component in usb-c that helps hold the connection tight?

I have 2 usb cables by 2 different manufacturers.
One I bought last year by some random company named 'SUNGUY' on amazon.
And more recently splurged for fancy Anker ones.

The Anker ones don't stay in as well as the SUNGUY one.
There's a subtle click of sorts for both, but much much more pronounced for the SUNGUY one.
I can dangle my phone by the cable with the SUNGUY one for example, but it'd fallout for the anker one.

I measured both connectors with a decent caliper and both came out to 2.41mm x 8.31mm +/- 0.02mm.
So I don't think it's the external part that's making the difference in the security of the connection.

I have tried other cables since, all behave like the Anker one.
Which is unfortunate because I want more like the SUNGUY one.
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07Z4BMRXG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Z4BMRXG)
is the SUNGUY cable. Nothing there seems to suggest it's special in anyway?

Comment: so, what's the question here? You have a cable that was cheap and doesn't work well. Great, probably means it's not made to the USB specification. Toss it.

Comment: check for compacted lint in the USB, socket especially if this is a pocket device. I would reccoment using a non-conductve tool to pick the lint out (eg toothpick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB-C plug has retention springs inside the shell:

[image: mechanical diagram]

(diagram excerpted from USB Type-C Cable and Connector Specification, Release 2.0).

The specified extraction force for a USB-C connector, from the same specification document, is between 8 and 20 newtons (1.8 - 4.5 lbf) when brand new and 6 and 20 newtons (1.35 - 4.5 lbf) after 10,000 insertion/removal cycles. The lower end of this is enough to "dangle" most phones (my phone masses 190g, which means it weighs about 1.9 N) as long as you don't swing or jerk it around.