# Stop USB-C plug from holding/clipping

Tags: usb-c

Apologies if this isn't the right StackExchange site to go to, seemed like the best option.

I 3D printed a phone cradle for myself that was built for use with right-angle USB connectors. My phone has a USB-C port and the cradle does its job, but with a minor annoyance: I have to hold the cradle down in order to remove my phone from it because the USB-C plug clips into place (as it normally should!).

But for the cables I'm using for my cradle(s), I'd like to stop them from clipping on so I can just slide my phone out of the cradle without needing both hands to do so. Is this possible?

While writing this question, I did find [this question and answer with a diagram that shows the retention springs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/501208/138536), and while I appreciate knowing where they are now, I can't easily envision a way to restrain, break, or remove the springs to accomplish what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way the USB-C connector is designed, and frankly, that's a good thing: there's actually quite a bit of current passing through pretty small contacts when charging a modern phone, so you really want to ensure contact is reliable.

So, your intent to remove the clipping is in opposition to using the connector as charging connector.

So, the much more boring mechanical solution is: Gluing, screwing, or otherwise affixing your cradle to something heavy enough for you to pull out your phone with one hand.